# Getting error when using set on a hasMany association

Tags: sequelize.js

I have an `Invoice` model which can be associated with multiple `LineItem` models. When I call `setLineItems(lineItems, {transaction: t});` (where `lineItems` is an array of `LineItem` objects) I get an error due to some really weird SQL being created by Sequelize behind the scnenes:

```
DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: invalid input syntax for integer: "[object Object]"
// Stack trace cut out
{
    name: 'error',
    length: 108,
    severity: 'ERROR',
    code: '22P02',
    detail: undefined,
    hint: undefined,
    position: '69',
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: undefined,
    table: undefined,
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: 'numutils.c',
    line: '62',
    routine: 'pg_atoi',
    sql: `UPDATE "LineItems" SET "invoiceId"=$1,"updatedAt"=$2 WHERE "id" IN ('[object Object]', '[object Object]')`,
    parameters: [ 8, '2020-04-25 06:56:19.482 +00:00' ]
}
```

My code/definitions are below:

invoice.js:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Invoice = sequelize.define('Invoice', {
        // various fields, including a numeric id
    }, {});
    Invoice.associate = function (models) {
        Invoice.hasMany(models.LineItem, { foreignKey: 'invoiceId' });
    };
    return Invoice;
};
```

lineItems.js:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const LineItem = sequelize.define('LineItem', {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        invoiceId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            references: {
                model: 'Invoices',
                key: 'id'
            },
        },
        hsnSacCode: DataTypes.STRING(30),
        desc: DataTypes.STRING(1500),
        qty: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10, 3),
        rate: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10, 3),
        amt: DataTypes.DECIMAL(16, 3)
    }, {});
    LineItem.associate = function (models) {
    };
    return LineItem;
};
```

The `Invoice` migration:

```
'use strict';

const tbl = 'Invoices';

module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.createTable(tbl, {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            // other fields
        });
    },
    down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.dropTable('Invoices');
    }
};
```

The `LineItem` migration:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.createTable('LineItems', {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            invoiceId: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                references: {
                    model: 'Invoices',
                    key: 'id'
                },
                onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
                onDelete: 'SET NULL'
            },
            hsnSacCode: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING(30)
            },
            desc: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING(1500)
            },
            qty: {
                type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10,3)
            },
            rate: {
                type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10,3)
            },
            amt: {
                type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(16,3)
            },
            createdAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATE
            },
            updatedAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATE
            }
        });
    },
    down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.dropTable('LineItems');
    }
};
```

What's strange is that the generated SQL is so wrong!! Sample:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO "Invoices" ("id","invoiceNum","vendorId","corporateId","dated","currency","preTaxAmt","igstPct","sgstPct","totalAmt","tdsPaid","gstInputCreditClaimed","status","vendorStatus","type","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16) RETURNING *;
SELECT "id", "invoiceId", "hsnSacCode", "desc", "qty", "rate", "amt", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "LineItems" AS "LineItem" WHERE "LineItem"."invoiceId" = 8;
UPDATE "LineItems" SET "invoiceId"=$1,"updatedAt"=$2 WHERE "id" IN ('[object Object]', '[object Object]')
ROLLBACK;
```

Here's the code that's executed:

```
const dbInvoice = await sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {
    const invoice = _.omit(input, ['lineItems']);
    const { lineItems } = _.pick(input, ['lineItems']);
    const dbInvoice = await Invoice.create(invoice, { transaction: t });
    console.log(`lineItems:`, lineItems);
    await dbInvoice.setLineItems(lineItems, {transaction: t});
    return Promise.resolve(dbInvoice.dataValues);
});
```

`console.log` output of `lineItems` just before I try to save it:

```
lineItems: [
  {
    hsnSacCode: 'arbit',
    desc: 'Daycare for Child1, Child2',
    qty: 2,
    rate: '2000.00',
    amt: '4000.00'
  },
  {
    hsnSacCode: 'arbit',
    desc: 'Daycare for Child1, Child2',
    qty: 1,
    rate: '2000.00',
    amt: '2000.00'
  }
]
```

If I stuff each `lineItem` with the `id` of the `Invoice` just saved, and then save them normally (i.e., without using `setLineItems(...)`), it works as expected.

Working with PostgresQL RDBMS.

Sequelize: [Node: 12.14.1, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.3

Comment: show an output from  console.log(`lineItems:`, lineItems);

Comment: @Anatoly Just added the `console.log` output of `lineItems`.

Comment: What if you try to add invoiceId: dbInvoice.id to each lineItem before create them?

Comment: @Anatoly I added the line `lineItems.forEach(li => { li.invoiceId = dbInvoice.dataValues.id; });` before calling `setLineItems()` & the result was the same. The `console.log()` output showed the added `invoiceId` field set to the correct value.

Comment: Also updated Sequelize to version `5.21.7` (from `5.21.3`), but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you create an example on https://codesandbox.io?

Comment: @Anatoly Setting up the DB will be hard... without that I don't how this example could be tried out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `setItems` with raw objects (more importantly, they're new objects).  You need to call `addItems` and then Sequelize will insert them and associate them for you.

I wish `setItems` was smart and created the items for you. It seems that even if the items are there in the DB, you can only call the `setX` associate methods with either an empty array or an array of Sequelize objects (not objects created manually with an `id` field or sent back from the browser, etc).

### How do I know which one to call?

The best way to do this is to save the items first before adding them to the Invoice. To say that loosely in code:

```
// Save the items first.
let savedItems = [];
for(const item of items) {
  let savedItem;
  if(item.id) {
    savedItem = await sequelize.Item.save(item);
  } else {
    savedItem = await sequelize.Item.create(item);
  }
  savedItems.push(savedItem);
}

// Now this will work.
await Invoice.setItems(savedItems);
```

Comment: I'll try that. In the meantime: how to I handle update situations? Sometimes the update of the Invoice will want to add new `lineItems`, sometimes it'll just be editing the existing `lineItems`. Could you update your answer with advice on that?

Comment: There. Is that better?